# Graphic Drivers

Tags: video

I just started using ubuntu yesterday ,and I like it but I have several problems

First

I think I have to install graphics drivers,I installed steam and downloaded team fortress 2,but it's laggy.I have nvidia geforce gt 650 m and intel hd 4000 graphics card(total 2 gb)

Second one

Not sure how but shadow gone,no more problem :)

Thank you everyone,have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have an optimus laptop.
To make use of your graphics card you must first install bumblebee:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-generic
sudo reboot
```

Then you'll need to wrap TF2 so that it runs on your geforce card rather than intel hd. See: http://steamcommunity.com/groups/LinuxOptimus/discussions/1/864951657813049306/#c864951657813051785 for details

Comment: Thanks for answer I'm using samsung 550p5c laptop,now I'm installing bumblebee

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, Ubuntu makes it extremely easy to install proprietary drivers, such as those necessary for your video card.

Simply open the "System Settings" application, and click on the "Additional Drivers" button. This should check your system to see if there are any devices which would benefit from additional drivers. Your Nvidia graphics card should allow you to install Nvidia's proprietary drivers.

Simply select the driver you want to use, and click "Activate". It should be functional after a reboot.